# How much does performance change with a VARCHAR or INT column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, integer, innodb, varchar

I have many tables, with millions of lines, with MySQL. Those tables are used to store log lines. 
I have a field "country" in VARCHAR(50). There is an index on this column.
Would it change the performances a lot to store a countryId in INT instead of this country field ?

Thank you !

Comment: an int is 1 byte, always. varchar is numchars+1 bytes. so yes it can havea  huge impact on speed

Comment: @user1281385: An `int` is not only 1 byte. That would make its range only from 0 to 256. But it is 4 bytes normally.

Comment: @juergend oops yeah good spot. The answer still stands though

Comment: Another point to consider is that countries sometimes change their names - meaning that foreign states come to recognise those countries under a new name - Burma -> Myanmar, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit more complicated than it first seems.  The simple answer is that `Country` is a string up to 50 characters.  Replacing it by a 4-byte integer should reduce the storage space required for the field.  Less storage means less I/O overhead in processing the query and smaller indexes.  There are outlier cases of course.  If `country` typically has a `NULL` value, then the current storage might be more efficient than having an id.

It gets a little more complicated, though, when you think about keeping the field up-to-date.   One difference with a reference table is that the countries are now standardized, rather than being ad-hoc names.  In general, this is a good thing.  On the other hand, countries do change over time, so you have to be prepared to add a "South Sudan" or "East Timor" now and then.

If your database is heavy on inserts/updates, then changing the country field requires looking in the reference table for the correct value -- and perhaps inserting a new record there.

My opinion is "gosh . . . it would have been a good idea to set the database up this way in the beginning".  At this point, you need to understand the effects on the application of maintaining a country reference table for the small performance gain of making the data structure more efficient and more accurate.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all the implications for the maintenance, and also for the disk sapces. I was mainly concerned with performance only ! I think I am going to change everything, even if it should take a little time. Even if the performance gain is small, it is still something !

Answer (score 1):

Indexes on INT values shows better performance than Indexes applied on string data types (VARCHAR).
because searching/matching an integer is always faster than a string and search algorithm implemented underneath of indexing works on same principle.

In your case you will get better performance with index on INT type than VARCHAR.